# How to extend model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two types of users (regular user, super user). What is the proper way to extend one base user class with additional tables?

I was thinking something like this but I am not sure am I going to right direction:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class SuperUser < User
end

class RegularUser < User
end
```

Is this the proper way to do it in Rails? Thanks :)

Comment: @bjhaid - It is called STI, polymorphic association is something else.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 100% correct approach, however you need to remember, that all your models will be stored in one table in database. This approach is called STI (Single table inheritance) and requires only one additional field `type` in you model.

Comment: Thank you. With type you mean, for example, to have in USER model integer which has a value 0 or 1 depending which user is active? Or a string "role" with values "super" or "regular". Something like that?

Comment: You need to have string `type` column. That's it, Rails will take care of its content.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have different types of users I would go with user roles versus different user tables etc.

A very good gem for that is CanCan and the documentation is excellent:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

You will also have nice helpers as .can? or .cannot? and more.

Comment: Thank you. I've already made my own authorization system :) I can do it like that but I would again have multiple different table columns for different users. If super user has additional 2 columns, regular user will also have those columns but they would be null. Or I am wrong?

Comment: It would be one additional table "roles" and a user can belong to certain roles. There would be no "unused" columns. It's a very clean approach and you should under all circumstances prevent having two different user tables (what if a regular user becomes an admin?). Another really simple approach could be to have a column called is_admin which is either true or false. I would go with a Role system though. It's more flexible as you can add multiple roles over time. How about a user is not really an admin but allowed to do "some" admin tasks? Could be an "editor" role or something like that

Comment: I was thinking about this but I think there would be some unused fields in my case. So, let's say I have three user types (admin, professor, student). Admin needs only these columns: username, last_name, first_name. Professor needs additional columns so he has: username, last_name, first_name, number_of_classes, salary. Student doesn't need those fields but needs some other so he has: username, last_name, first_name, average_grade, number_of_passed_classes. If there is only one table "roles", wouldn't I have one big User table with many columns unused? For example, average_grad for prof.

Comment: You would have tables like salaries and classes (better chose a different name to never clash with class which is reserved keyword). Then you would set "has_one :salary" and "has_many :classes" to your user model. Now you can query User.first.classes and get her/his classes or nothing (if a student) etc. That's what's called normalization and you would have no empty fields, just users without data in certain tables.

Comment: Thank you. I was never thinking to model it like that :) So, I would have new classes Salary, NumberOfClasses, AverageGrade and NumberOfPassedClasses for this case i mentioned?

Comment: I would do Salary class (which has a id, user_id (which it belongs to) and amount. Then a Klass class (don't clash with keywords - find different name). Between Klass and User I would set a many-to-many relationship. An excellent guide for all these scenarios is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: And AverageGrade and NumberOfPassedClasses you would stay in main table, right? Sorry because of many questions but all this is pretty new to me. This is the last question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you should also use single table inheritance.  What this means is you should add a column called 'type' to your user model.  Rails recognizes the column 'type' and treats it special.  Essentially, all entries in your type model will reference another model.  In that model, you can define rules for each type.  It would also be a good idea to validate your user model so that only the two types you want can be entered.  This should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :type, :inclusion => {:in => ['SuperUser', 'RegularUser']}
end
```